# Comprehensive test-case(s) for finding all cycles in a directed graph?

Tags: unit-testing, cycle, directed-graph

I've implemented an algorithm for finding all cycles in a directed graph. I think it's correct, but I won't leave that to intuition. I've written a number of simple tests, but I'm not sure I handled all edge cases (or vertex cases... Hehe, I'll be here all week).

Anyway, I'm sure I'm not the first one doing this. Can anyone point me to an existing test-suite, i.e., a comprehensive set of directed graphs plus a list of their cycles?